# MS SQL php query comma separated column?

Tags: php, mysql, odbc

I am totally new to MS SQL querying, what I have is three tables set as follows:

Users table with a column (userGroupLocID) set as data type of varchar, this field contains values that are comma separated for example (1,2)

Room_Location table with a column (user_loc_id) set s data type INT

Client_Room table with a column (id) set as data type INT

I have the following query which works `$query = "SELECT * FROM client_room, room_location, users WHERE $useractiveid = (users.id) AND client_room.id = (room_location.user_loc_id)";`

This outputs a full list of locations from the Room_Location table which is ok this works but I only want locations to be displayed where an id exists in the user table (userGroupLocID) `$query = "SELECT * FROM client_room, room_location, users WHERE $useractiveid = (users.id) AND client_room.id = (room_location.user_loc_id) AND cast(client_room.id as varchar(10)) IN (users.userGroupLocID)";`

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong please.

Comment: its the query the problem? or its the execution of the query the problem?
if its the execution the query, how are you executing it?

Comment: It's the query that's the problem, thanks!

Comment: Please see amended question above with how I am trying to execute it.

Comment: you are changing to ODBC because of another database? if so wich (not mysql)

Comment: There's no odbc_connect in your code sample and no error checking

Comment: The error I receive is "FIND_IN_SET' is not a recognized built-in function name"

Comment: Can anyone help with the following query please.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to solve my own question, it's probably not the best answer but it was the only way it was going to work on MS SQl.

```
<select name="event_room" id="event_room">
                        <option>Room Location</option>
                        <?php 

                            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE theusername = '$userident'";

                            $result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);

                            while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)){

                                $usegrids = explode(',', $userperenco);
                                foreach ($usegrids as $usegrid) {
                                    $querygroup = "SELECT * FROM room_location WHERE user_loc_id = '$usegrid'";
                                    $resultgroup = odbc_exec($connect, $querygroup);
                                    while($rowgroup = odbc_fetch_array($resultgroup)){
                                        echo "<option value=\"" . $rowgroup['location'] . "\">" . $rowgroup['location'] . "</option>\n";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
```